# auto_prepend_file deletes first line of apended file

Tags: php, .htaccess, prepend

When using php.ini with

```
auto_prepend_file=/homepages/xyz/htdocs/somefile.php
```

on the file thickbox.css (for some reasons I have to process css files as php), the first line gets deleted. The beginning of thickbox.css is

```
#TB_overlay {
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100050; /* Above DFW. */
}
```

but the output with a prepended file is

```
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100050; /* Above DFW. */
}
```

The first line is gone!

When I just place a blank before the # or a linebreak, the line reappear. But as soon as the first character is a # the first line is gone.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I have two hypothesis so far: 1) `somefile.php` contains PHP code that does such a thing 2) You are not inspecting the raw output but the result of some further post-processing. Are you 100% sure that your PHP code is not relevant to the issue? How do you verify the line is not there?

Comment: I use `somefile.php` just for header output. But even if `somefile.php` is blank and contains nothing, the fist line of `thickbox.css` is deleted, when starting with a `#`.

Comment: I can verify this by calling the processed `thickbox.css` with a web-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The requested css-file should not just be appended. Instead the 'somefile.php' should output the requested file itself with the following lines at the end:

```
readfile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); // the requested file
exit(0);
```